# removing text between pipe and comma

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a enormous long file with the text separated as

```
subtlechanges|NEW=19647490,subtlec|NEW=19638255
```

and I want the text like

```
subtlechanges,subtle.
```

I tried using the \|.*$ but it is removing everything after the first pipe. Any guess. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify? You want all occurrences of |NEW=<number>, to disappear?

Comment: Yes tink I want all the occurrence of the |NEW=* to disappear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, we have a file that may look like:

```
$ cat file
subtlechanges|NEW=19647490,subtle|NEW=19638255
```

And, we want to remove everything from a pipe character to the next comma.  In that case:

```
$ sed 's/|[^,]*//g' file
subtlechanges,subtle
```

#### How it works

In sed, substitute commands look like `s/old/new/g` where `old` is a regular expression for what is removed, `new` is what gets substituted in, and the final `g` signifies that we want to do this not just once per line but as many times per line as we can.

The regular expression that we use for `old` here is `|[^,]*`.  This matches a pipe, `|`, and any characters after up to, but not including, the first comma.

Comment: Thanks John. I just figured out the same

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using comma *or* pipe as the field separator, print the 1st, 3rd, ... every odd field.

```
awk -F '[,|]' '{
    sep=""
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, $i
        sep=","
    }
    print ""
}' file
```